# Nexus 9 Camera2 API - YUV_420_888 vs. getOutputSizes()

Tags: android, android-camera, yuv

I'm implementing the Camera2 API with the YUV_420_888 format on a Nexus 9.  I checked the output sizes and wanted to use the largest (8MP, 3280 x 2460) size to save.  However, it just appears as static lines, similar to how old TV's looked without a signal. I would like to stick with YUV_420_888 since my end goal is to save grayscale data (Y component).

I originally thought it was a camera bandwidth issue, but the same thing happened at some of the small sizes (320 x 240).  None of the problems went away even when I increased frame duration and decreased the size of the preview to save on bandwidth.  Some of the other sizes DID work (2048 x 1536, 1280 x 720) but I did not check all of them.

I'm starting to think getOutputSizes() may not necessarily be accurate.  It gave me the same results for all other formats except RAW_SENSOR (JPEG, YUV_420_888, YV12).  Has anyone encountered this or determined a solution?

Comment: What are you actually doing to save the data in this format? Maybe there is an issue with that code.

Comment: Well I just wrote two text files: one from the bytes directly from: 

    ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    buffer.get(bytes);

And the unsigned char array that I'm saving directly on the C++ side.  The two match identically, so I do believe it's the data coming from the camera that is corrupt.

Comment: Can you include what other outputs you're using in the capture session, and what version of Android you're on? This sounds like a potential bug in the Nexus 9, as what you've described so far should just work.

Comment: @EddyTalvala - I am on Android 5.0.1, build LRX22C.  I am only using a mImageReader and the live camera preview.  The majority of it is from Camera2Basic but slimmed down since I do not need to lockFocus or anything like that.

Comment: Are you having preview run for a while (and preview looks good) before capturing the high-resolution image? Or are you just grabbing a single frame right after camera open?  The latter is risky, as the auto-exposure routine won't have yet converged to good values.

Comment: I run the preview first.  It takes me some time to setup the capture (I enter in the number of pictures I'd like to capture).  Then, every second I captureStillPicture().  

Also, I manually set both the exposure and focus with CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME and CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, respectively when I createCaptureSession() (preview) and captureStillPicture().

Comment: @EddyTalvala - does the Camera API processing code (that converts to jpeg, YUV, etc) change with operating system?  As in, could the Android M preview fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.  I was not taking into account the rowStride of the returned pixels.  So I had to run a for-loop to extract the non-padded data before saving it:

```
myRowStride = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getRowStride();
int iSkippedBytes = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < mStillSize.getWidth() * mStillSize.getHeight(); i++){
    if (i % mStillSize.getWidth() == 0 && i != 0)
          iSkippedBytes = iSkippedBytes + (myRowStride - mStillSize.getWidth());
    imageBytes[i] = bytes[i + iSkippedBytes];
 }
```

Comment: Additionally you might want to check byte stride too. It isn't always 1.

Comment: For YUV_420_888, isn't the Y component pixelstride always 1 byte?

Comment: You are totally right, it's U and V which may have different pixel stride. Pardon me.